# Design bundle and Document Bundle

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Why we use Design bundle and Documentation Bundle in lightning component?

Answer (score 1):

**Design bundle** - when we edit lightning page we can input attribute values specified .
example:

```
https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/10/03/design-resource-lightning-component/
```

**Documentation** - It's just about that component. It would be useful for developers who would work on it in future. We can see the details in `https://lightning.force.com/componentReference`

example:

```
https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/documentation-in-salesforce-lightning-component-bundle/
```